# Python: Finding number of fitting parameters for arbitrary curve

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

Is there a way to return the number of arguments an arbitrary function has which is defined in some other file? I have tried using the Signature class in inspect as follows:

```
from foo import func1, func2, func3
from inspect import signature
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

func_list = [ func1, func2, func3 ]

n, bins, patches = hist( array )

for f in func_list:
    sig = signature(f)
    args = sig.parameters['args']

    p = np.ones( len(args) )

    params = curve_fit( f, bins[1:], n, p0 = p )
    print(params[0])
```

But this doesn't do what I need as signature, from what I've seen, only works for local user-defined functions.

The place where the problem lies here is that I have a test function (modified Gaussian) within a class which takes one required parameter (the input array) and three parameters for fitting:

```
def _pdf( self, x, a, b, c ):
    return np.sqrt(a) * ( np.exp(-(b*x)**2 / c ) / np.sqrt(2.0 * np.pi) )
```

I wish the value of `len( params[0] )` to be 3 in the above example.

The initialisation of np.ones is arbitrary (as I know not stating a p0 will give the number of arguments all at a guess of 1) but I which to modify this array in the future. Right now, I just need to be able to determine the length of p0 manually.

Context: I want to fit some curve parameters using scipy but I don't know how many fitting parameters each curve will have until the user loads them in.

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: This kind of inspect will not be possible due to the way in which `scipy` wants its models to be defined. So you would have to get that info from somewhere else, for example a dict mapping functions to the number of parameters. Alternatively, if you wouldn't mind trying another package I would recommend using [symfit](https://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/ex_CallableNumericalModel.html) for this. It's a package I wrote to make fitting a lot easier. In `symfit`, you could request `len(Model.params)` to get the number of parameters of the model.

Comment: For a function named "func" in a file imported as "filename",  try using "argumentCount = filename.func.__code__.co_argcount" and see if it gives you the total number of function arguments.

Comment: Why can't you use `len(sig.parameters)`, and adjust that value to account for the first argument `x` and possibly `self` if the function comes from the class definition rather than an instance of the class?

Comment: Your test function is `_pdf(self, x, a, b, c)`, but in your code you try to use `sig.parameters['args']`, and there is no `args` parameter in your test function.  Are you actually trying to use functions that have a signature of the form `func(x, *args)`?  If so, please include the details in the question.  It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So, I have pdfs which have a, b, c as the arguments but when I print the signature of these curves, it just says "(x, *args, **kwds)". I think what is happening is the signature is being inherited from rv_continuous and I don't know how to overwrite this.

Comment: Don't forget that scipy is open source, so you could just go look at what `curve_fit` itself does, and do the same.  That will lead you to the function `getargspec_no_self` in the file [`_util.py`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/_lib/_util.py). (Edit: I was writing this comment before your last comment appeared; this comment is not a response to that one.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser this comment was super helpful as I love seeing how my packages work! However, I cannot seem to shake off this rv_continuous inheritance.